# Splitting a string into a specified number of substrings probabilistically based on substring training data

Tags: machine-learning, similarity, markov-chains

As part of a data processing pipeline, I'm building out a raw string parser. Each string is composed of substrings, which I want to parse the string into. There are 5 categories of substrings, and they include *names,* *addresses,* *unique identifiers,* and the like. For each string to split, I also (thankfully) can be assumed to know how many substrings (N) are contained within. So

```
"2452341 John Doe 5050 Fake street New York, NY, 43092", 3 substrings
```

Would ideally produce:

```
["2452341", "John Doe", "5050 Fake street New York, NY, 43092"]
```

Additionally, substrings may appear in any order within the main string. There is always a space between each substring. Substrings also contain spaces, so the trick is figuring out when a space is acting as a delimiter versus when it is merely a component of a substring.

I have a large amount (100k +) of example 'substrings' I can train a probabilistic parser on, but I'm not sure quite how to go about doing this. I have some rough ideas, though:

**Idea 1 - Markov Modeling**

Should I be using a Markov model to evaluate, for each character, the chance that it is the end of a substring, and then select the N most likely points?

If I assume a two state Markov chain, and then take every permutation of possible substring splits (at every " ") in a given string, and maximize the probability of state switches across those permutations, I should have my answer. What I can't seem to figure out is how I use my training data to get the probability of a switch at a given point.

**Idea 2 - Similarity to the training data**

Alternatively, there seems to be a method where I maximize the similarity of all of the possible to generate substrings to the training data, and select the most similar permutation. Is there a method for computing similarity of a single string to a group of strings?

Thanks much.